# Java Overwriting an existing class method

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, junit

I got a slightly complex issue.

The situation is that I work on a project for automization of selenium-based JUnittests. For this reason I write a testsuite and an abstractTestclass (as base for several testclasses). Also I try to structure my project so that the programmer who has to implement the testcases only has to record them in the selenium IDE and export to JUnit-test-classes. To reach this aim there are some changes required because some methods and functions of the thrown selenium-java-code and the standard selenium packages have little bugs... Such like IE doesn't click sometimes... 
To avoid those bugs I override the FFDriver and IEDriver class and especially the 'findElement' method. That works fine!

But now I got a new problem. It's the known problem that IE sometimes doesn't click on non-displayed elements. I also have a workaround (Use Javascript-command instead of click()). But as I thought about how to implement I want to do this like the problems I solved with overriding the driver classes and I started override the RemoteWebElement class.

And here comes the problem. If I override the RemoteWebElement class for overriding the click() method I have to use my new RemoteWebElement2_0 class over the whole project instead of the standard. At first guess thats not as worse as it seems (like I have to do the same with the Driver classes). But then I realize that my findElement method delivers a RemoteWebElement not my RemoteWebElement2_0. I see no chance to change the findElement method to deliver my RemoteWebElement2_0 and downcast is not possible.

I have the following ideas to fix this problem but don't know how to implement them or even if the are implementable:

- 1.) override directly the original RemoteWebElement class (should be possible but how?)
- 2.) avoid returning a normal RemoteWebElement in the findElement method
- 3.) modify the selenium IDE to doesn't use click() method but a costum implementation
- 4.) solve the problem with the click() method with another workaround
- 5.) downcasting is not possible!?

Could anyone help me? I know it's a little bit strange but please try to understand me and be not aware to ask if you doesn't!

Here is my Code:

the IEDriver class -->

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement;

public class InternetExplorerDriver2_0 extends InternetExplorerDriver {

    private static InternetExplorerDriver2_0 instance = null;
    private long startTime;
    private long stopTime;
    private By olderBy;

    private InternetExplorerDriver2_0() {
        super();
    }

    public static synchronized InternetExplorerDriver2_0 getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new InternetExplorerDriver2_0();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteWebElement2_0 findElement(By by) {
        return elementSearch(by, InternetExplorerDriver2_0.getInstance());
    }

    private RemoteWebElement2_0 elementSearch(By by,
            InternetExplorerDriver driver) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        RemoteWebElement helpingElement = null;
        RemoteWebElement2_0 h2 = null;
        isElementPresent(by);
        try {

            //this not allowed downcast causes problems :(

            helpingElement = (RemoteWebElement) super.findElement(by);
            h2 = (RemoteWebElement2_0) helpingElement;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[error] method 'elementSearch' incomplete" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            fail("Test not successfull!");
        } finally {
            stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            timeWarning(by.toString());
        }
        olderBy = by;
        return h2;
    }

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
            super.findElement(by);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e1) {
            try {
                InternetExplorerDriver2_0.getInstance().findElement(olderBy).click();
                super.findElement(by);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                timeWarning(by.toString());
                AllTest.updateLogger("[main] ERROR\tThe following expression could not be solved: " + by);
                fail("Test not successfull! --> Error: Element not found. Please check the failed XPath's");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void timeWarning(String s) {
        if (stopTime - startTime > 500) {
            AllTest.updateLogger("[main] WARNING\tHigh response-time detected: " + (stopTime - startTime) + " ms [@element: " + s + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

The RemoteWebDriver2_0 class -->

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement;

public class RemoteWebElement2_0 extends RemoteWebElement {

    public RemoteWebElement2_0() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void click() {
        try {
            super.click();
        } catch (ElementNotVisibleException e1) {

            //Here starts the workaround for the IEDriver.click problem

            try {
                RemoteWebDriver helpDriver = (RemoteWebDriver) this.getWrappedDriver();
                helpDriver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", this.getWrappedDriver().findElement(By.id("eb_format_12h")));
            } catch (Exception e2) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need some more Code please ask for it.

Thanks upwards!!!

Comment: make your `RemoteWebElement2_0` holds instance of original `RemoteWebElement` object and delegates all methods (except click which you want to override)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't follow you, how do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not expert in selenium, but what you could do is to return wrapper for original `RemoteWebElement`

in your `InternetExplorerDriver2_0` override method

```
  @Override
    public RemoteWebElement findElement(By by) {
      RemoteWebElement originalElement = super.findElement(by);
      if (originalElement == null){
      return null;
      }
      return new RemoteWebElementWrapper(originalElement);
    }
```

now create wrapper class, and override all methods from superclass like in example below

```
public class RemoteWebElementWrapper extends RemoteWebElement {

    private final RemoteWebElement instance;
    public RemoteWebElementWrapper(RemoteWebElement instance) {
        super();
        this.instance = instance;
    }
@Override
List<WebElement> findElementsByLinkText(String using){
return instance.findElementsByLinkText(using)
}
@Override
List<WebElement> findElementsByName(String using){
instance.findElementsByName(using)
}
@Override
List<WebElement>    findElementsByPartialLinkText(String using){
instance.findElementsByPartialLinkText(using)
}
//etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you, this solution works for me. It's little bit complex but it works!:)